# Pass argument without method PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a question regarding the MVC design pattern in PHP.

If you visit a question on Stack Overflow the URL becomes "stackoverflow.com/questions/[id]", and if you go to "Ask Question" the URL becomes "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".

I suppose this generally means that a controller named "questions" is loaded, and "ask" is a method in that controller that tells the view to display a form in order for the user to ask a question. But when you visit a question, there is no method, right? Instead there is an ID of the question. How does that work? Does the page first check if it is a number, and if it is it a number it loads the index method of the questions controller and passes the ID as a parameter? And if it isn´t a number it treats it as a method?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a question, you could have the action as "view", but generally its preferred to use an "index" action. Any requests to the "questions" controller without a specified action could be routed there.

Comment: But if I visit this question,(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106279), desn´t that mean that the site tries to run a method called 10106279 inside the questions controller?

Comment: That's right, an MVC stack will typically have routing rules. Where you could flag the last section of the URL as an ID. You could apply any routing logic you like. You could make the route "/beans" go to controller "johnny", and action "rogers".

Comment: Sometime you gonna have a model that do something but you'll want it from the home page also so your home page will call the model from sub page weather let's say, you could do a controller named ajax and load it from everywhere also... it's only redirection who follow a designed path I'll say.

Answer (score 0):

They just parse the URL in questions_controller, using conditional statement they will be routed to their view's such as,

if it is "ask" it call's UI of questioning.

When it is an id it just load's the UI of the question with its answers.

Comment: So it has to check if it is a number? Otherwise it can´t know if it is a method or an ID, right?

Comment: @piers I dont know how they are using it. But am using my controllers to route in this way.

Comment: This is how I'd do too... my init function in my controller will chick if it's integer or not and route whatever needed... MVC is easy. You get the page to the controller then you do whatever you want with your parameters, models, views, actions, etc.